# Count distinct values depending on group

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

I have a table called "test" and two of the columns look like this:

```
identifier     group
12             a
35             c
87             b
35             c
22             c
....
```

This continues on for thousands of rows. What I want to find out is how many distinct identifiers there are for each "group". So for example using the above table the group "c" would have 2 identifiers, the same identifier can appear more than once for each group; 35 appears twice for group c but i want it to only count it once.

Ideally the ouput would be two columns, something like this:

```
group   distinct_id_count
a       1
b       1
c       2
... (these number would be much larger and there would be hundreds of more grouping in the actual table)
```

I was thinking to over partition by the row number but I can't quite work out how it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `count(distinct)`:

```
select "group", count(distinct id)
from t
group by "group";
```

Note that `group` is a very poor name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.  Hopefully the real column name is something more reasonable.